# How to perform summation for regular expression match results in python

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to extract certain numbers from multiple files and perform a summation for the extracted numbers here is what i have written till now

```
import re, os
path = "F:/s"
in_files = os.listdir(path)

for g in in_files:
    file = os.path.join(path, g)
    text = open(file, "r")
    a = text.readlines()
    b = a[6]
    m = re.search('\t(.+?)\n', b)
    if m:
        found = m.group()
        print (found)
```

Extraction is working i get the results like this.

```
122
74
97
```

Now i want to sum all these numbers.

Comment: Try to append all those number in a list and perform sum function on it. 

>>> l=[1,2,3]

>>> sum(l)
6

Comment: I have tried print type(found)
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
So how to join 3 strings into a list so that i can perform sum(thatlist)

Comment: Then do the type casting to 'int' - int(found)

Comment: @PriyankPatel `sum()` is a built-in, you should not advice using `sum` as a variable name. `total` is usually used in python instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an empty list above your loop and instead of printing, just append `found` to that list. You can then sum the contents of that list (if everything goes well you should end up with a list of 'strings of integers').

```
import re, os
path = "F:/s"
in_files = os.listdir(path)
l = []
for g in in_files:
  ...
  ...
  if m:
    found = m.group()
    l.append(found)
```

Your list should look like this now: `['122', '74', '97']`,
so you can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map) and [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sum) to find the total (outside the loop):

```
print sum(map(int, l)) # 293
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets do it using `re.findall()`

```
count = 0
for number in re.findall('\t(.+?)\n', b):
    ## add int(number.strip()) to count
```

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: import re, os
    path = "F:/s"
    in_files = os.listdir(path)
    
    for g in in_files:
    file = os.path.join(path, g)
    text = open(file, "r")
    a = text.readlines()
    b = a[6]
    count = 0
    for number in re.findall('\t(.+?)\n', b):
        g = int(number.strip())
        print sum(g)

Comment: @user3415874 remove `print sum(g)` and replace it with `count = count + g`. Then outside the `for` loop, do `print count`

Comment: @user3415874 - That sum() function works on List. So you have to declare g=[] and then append g.append(int(number.strip())). And then outside the loop perform sum(g).

Comment: count = 0
    g =[]
    for number in re.findall('\t(.+?)\n', b):
        g.append(int(number.strip()))
        print g
returns 
[122]
[74]
[97]

Comment: @user3415874 Declare g=[] above your for loop.

Comment: gsts.pl was run and results were yielded at Fri Mar 14 05:54:44 2014
Table 1
Motif(-mer)  total
1 6478
2 977
3 253
4 74
5 22
6 5
this is the portion of input file i have multiple files with same structure but line 7 value is different'

Comment: '1 6478 2 977 3 253 4 74 5 22 6 5' Are you getting these complete as output and you want to sum it up ?